# containsNone() behaviour?

Tags: apex, string, debug

I have a string like this `bla bla`. In my class I have code like this:

```
String str = 'bla bla';
system.debug(str.containsNone(', '));  //debug result FALSE
system.debug(str.containsNone(','));   //debug result TRUE
```

First debug outputs `false` and second one outputs `true` while [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_containsNone) says:

> containsNone(substring):
>   Returns true if the current String doesn’t contain the specified sequence of characters; otherwise, returns false.

According to this output must be `false` for both.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the phrasing is poor, but `containsNone` is not simply `!contains`, which is how you are interpreting it. A more correct description might be:

> containsNone(substring): Returns true if the current String doesn’t contain any of the specified characters; otherwise, returns false.

Because your string contains the space character, it returns `false`.

Comment: I nominate @AdrianLarson to create the Apex doc feedback to SFDC :-)

Comment: @crop1645 I hope Adrian does. I just met our docs team and they take feedback very seriously

Comment: So it is the opposite of `containsAny(substring)` :)

Comment: @abdn Yep. Sure makes a lot more sense that way!